# MarkLogic : Can't read the XML document due to Entity reference issue in URI

Tags: marklogic

In MarkLogic DB the data has been inserted in below URI format.

Sample : `doc(/Antony/Test_28_7&8_7-8_3.xml)`

But in this URI Entity reference value also included so this document can't read in to MarkLogic DB and I get an error like:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP:ENTITYREF:(err:XPST003) invalid entity refernce "8".

Is there any other way to open or reingest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & is a not very convenient, but valid character in a MarkLogic document uri. Keep in mind though, that & (and other special characters) might require escaping when trying to access the document. This is the case with for instance XQuery, and the REST api. In XQuery you'd use:

```
fn:doc("/Antony/Test_28_7&amp;8_7-8_3.xml")
```

With REST, you'd access it with this url:

```
/v1/documents?uri=%2FAntony%2FTest_28_7%268_7-8_3.xml
```

HTH!